# Passport openid-connect strategy not authenticating when I redirect from a page to Login Routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, openid, openid-connect

Now These routes below function properly when I hit them directly but when I am redirecting a user them from a page to these routes the authentication is never successful instead I am redirected back to the route '/auth/openidconnect/undefined'. 
Moreover Something that I found really weird was that after trying at least 2 more times (redirecting the user to the auth route from the above mentioned page) I get successfully authenticated.

````
    router.get('/auth/openidconnect',oidcSettings, oidcProviderReq);
    router.get('/auth/openidconnect/callback',oidcSettings, oidcCallback);

let oidcSettings = function (req, res, next) {

      //provider contains all the required data

        var OidcStrategy = require('passport-openidconnect').Strategy;
        passport.use('oidc', new OidcStrategy({
            issuer: provider.settings.issuer,
            authorizationURL: provider.settings.authorizationURL,
            tokenURL: provider.settings.tokenURL,
            userInfoURL: provider.settings.userInfoURL,
            clientID: provider.settings.ClientID,
            clientSecret: provider.settings.clientSecret,
            callbackURL: provider.settings.callbackURL, 
            scope: 'openid profile'
        }, (issuer, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, done) => {
            if (!(profile && profile._json && profile._json.email)) {
                return done(null, false);
            }
            req.params.provider =profile.id
            oidcLogin(req, profile, 'oidc_user', done); //basically either logs into the application or creates a new user 
        }));
        next();
}

let oidcProviderReq = function(req, res, next){
    passport.authenticate('oidc', {scope: 'openid profile'})(req, res, next);
}

let oidcCallback = function(req, res, next){
    passport.authenticate('oidc', function (err, user, info) {
        if(err) throw err;
       console.log(user)
    })(req, res, next);
}




```
````

Comment: Hey were you able to solve this?